# Form.show() does not respond

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a small postIt programm which should enable the user to send little notes to other computers using a database.
I have a main-Form where I can write messages and see users online, a sheet-form which should display messages and a sql database which has a table for users and messages.

The idea is that I am writing messages into the  Messagestable and my programm uses [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) to get the new messages and to show them in sheets. So far so good.

The problem is when I add a new Message to my table the SqlDependency fires an Event and my mainForm creates a new sheet which freezes after sheet.Show() is called. The mainForm keeps on running but my sheets always do not respond.

Here's my code:
DBListener:

```
 Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.Sql
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Threading

Public Class DBListener

    Private changeCount As Integer = 0

    Private Const tableName As String = "IMSMessages"
    Private Const statusMessage As String = _
       "{0} changes have occurred."
    Private exitRequested As Boolean = False
    Private waitInProgress As Boolean = False
    Private recieverHost As String
    Private imsMain As IMSMain

    Public Sub New(main As IMSMain, recieverHost As String)
        Me.imsMain = main
        Me.recieverHost = recieverHost
        initCommand(recieverHost)
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString)
        GetMsg(recieverHost)
    End Sub


    Private connectionString As String = "Data Source=NB_RANDY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eurom_test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Private sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Private commandMesg As SqlCommand = Nothing
    Private commandUsers As SqlCommand = Nothing

    Private Sub initCommand(recieverHost As String)
        commandMesg = New SqlCommand
        commandMesg.CommandText = "SELECT MessageID,SenderHost,RecieverHost,isRead,isRecieved,Stamp from dbo.IMSMessages " &
                                       "WHERE RecieverHost=@RecieverHost" &
                                       " AND isRecieved = 0"
        commandMesg.Parameters.Add("@RecieverHost", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = recieverHost
        commandMesg.Connection = sqlConn

        commandUsers = New SqlCommand
        commandUsers.CommandText = "Select HostName From dbo.IMSUser"
    End Sub




    Private Sub OnChangeMsg(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs)
        Dim dep As SqlDependency = DirectCast(sender, SqlDependency)
        RemoveHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf OnChangeMsg
        GetMsg(recieverHost)
    End Sub
    Private Sub OnChangeUser(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs)
        Dim dep As SqlDependency = DirectCast(sender, SqlDependency)
        RemoveHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf OnChangeUser
        GetUsers()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetMsg(recieverHost As String)
        If Not sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            sqlConn.Open()

        End If

        commandMesg.Notification = Nothing
        Dim dep As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(commandMesg)
        AddHandler dep.OnChange, New OnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf OnChangeMsg)
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(commandMesg)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        imsMain.recieveNewMessages(table)
    End Sub
    Public Sub GetUsers()
        If Not sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            sqlConn.Open()

        End If

        commandMesg.Notification = Nothing
        Dim dep As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(commandUsers)
        AddHandler dep.OnChange, New OnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf OnChangeUser)
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable   
        imsMain.updateOnlineUserList()
    End Sub


End Class
```

IMSMain-Form:

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Threading

    Public Class IMSMain

    Private user As IMSUser
    Private listener As DBListener


    Private sqlConn As SqlConnection

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        sqlConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NB_RANDY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eurom_test;Integrated Security=SSPI;")



        Me.user = New IMSUser(My.Computer.Name)
        user.register()

        updateOnlineUserList()
        listener = New DBListener(Me, user.HostName)

    End Sub
    Private Sub onSend(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_send.Click
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        Dim msgText = tb_text.Text
        Dim reciever As IMSUser = lb_Online.SelectedItem
        Dim insert_string As String = "Insert INTO dbo.IMSMessages(Text,RecieverHost,SenderHost,isRead,isRecieved,Stamp) Values(@Text,@RecieverHost,@SenderHost,@isRead,@isRecieved,@Stamp)"
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Try

            If Not sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                sqlConn.Open()

            End If
            command.Connection = sqlConn
            command.CommandText = insert_string
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(table)
            command.CommandText = insert_string
            command.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = msgText
            command.Parameters.Add("@RecieverHost", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = reciever.HostName
            command.Parameters.Add("@SenderHost", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = user.HostName
            command.Parameters.Add("@isRecieved", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0
            command.Parameters.Add("@isRead", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0
            command.Parameters.Add("@Stamp", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("onSend: internal database exception" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub processMessageId(refMessageID As Integer)
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        Dim msgID_string As String = "SELECT * from dbo.IMSMessages " &
                                       "WHERE MessageID=@MessageID AND isRecieved = 0" &
                                       " ORDER BY Stamp"
        Dim isRecievedUpdate_string As String = "Update dbo.IMSMessages " &
                                            "SET isRecieved=1" &
                                             " WHERE MessageID=@MessageID"
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Try
            If Not sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                sqlConn.Open()

            End If
            command = New SqlCommand
            command.CommandText = msgID_string
            command.Parameters.Add("@MessageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = refMessageID
            command.Connection = sqlConn
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(table)
            command = New SqlCommand
            command.Connection = sqlConn
            command.CommandText = isRecievedUpdate_string
            command.Parameters.Add("@MessageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = refMessageID
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("processMessageID: internal database exception" + ex.Message)
        End Try
        Try
            Dim row As DataRow = table.Rows(0)
            Dim senderHost As String = row("SenderHost")
            Dim sender As IMSUser = New IMSUser(senderHost)
            Dim currentSheet As IMSSheet
            Dim stringText As String = row("Text")
            Dim stamp As Date = row("Stamp")
            currentSheet = New IMSSheet(sender, stringText, stamp)
            currentSheet.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("processMessageID: error while showing sheet")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub recieveNewMessages(newMessageTable As DataTable)
        For Each row As DataRow In newMessageTable.Rows
            Dim id As Integer = row("MessageID")
            processMessageId(id)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub updateOnlineUserList()
        lb_Online.Items.Clear()
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        Dim onlineUser_string = "Select * FROM dbo.IMSUser"
        command.CommandText = onlineUser_string
        Try
            If Not sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                sqlConn.Open()

            End If
            command.Connection = sqlConn
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(table)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("internal database exception" + ex.Message)
        End Try
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

            Dim tmp As IMSUser = New IMSUser(row("HostName"))
            If Not user.Equals(tmp) Then
                lb_Online.Items.Add(tmp)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

IMSSheet-Form:

```
    Public Class IMSSheet
        Dim IsDraggingForm As Boolean = False
        Private MousePos As New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)

    Public Sub New(session As IMSUser, text As String, stamp As Date)
        Ini

tializeComponent()
            Me.tb_sender.Text = session.HostName
            addText(text, stamp)
        End Sub

        Private Sub addText(msg As String, stamp As DateTime)
            Dim currentText As String = tb_text.Text
            currentText = currentText + stamp.ToString + Environment.NewLine + msg + Environment.NewLine
            tb_text.Text = currentText
        End Sub
        Private Sub IMSSheet_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
            If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
                IsDraggingForm = True
                MousePos = e.Location
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub IMSSheet_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
            If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then IsDraggingForm = False
        End Sub

        Private Sub IMSSheet_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
            If IsDraggingForm Then
                Dim temp As Point = New Point(Me.Location + (e.Location - MousePos))
                Me.Location = temp
                temp = Nothing
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub onClose(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_Close.Click
            Me.Close()
        End Sub


        Private Sub bt_minimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_minimize.Click
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        End Sub

        Private Sub bt_Close_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_Close.MouseHover

        End Sub

        Private Sub bt_minimize_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_minimize.MouseHover

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Interesting is that if I have already some new Messages in my Messagestable before I run the programm they are going to be displayed correctly.
If I display the sheets using Form.ShowDialog() it works as well but its not how I want it to work.

As I am out of ideas I hope you can help me.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the Show() call.  When it breaks, use Debug + Windows + Threads to see what thread the code is running on.  Pretty high odds that you'll find out that it is *not* on the main UI thread of your program.  Which leaves the form dead as a doornail.  You'll need to use Control.BeginInvoke() to get your code to run on the UI thread where the form has a chance to be functional.

Comment: Could your Catch block be catching an exception, that you can't see, because you're using Console.Writeline with a form app?  Try using MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) instead.

Comment: thanks.. Im going to try what you mentioned. @tinstaafl I already tried to catch any exception but there was none... and you are right Im now using Debug instead of Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into issues because the change event of `SqlDependency` occurs on a different thread that your UI thread.  From the [SqlDepending documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx):

> The OnChange event may be generated on a different thread from the
>   thread that initiated command execution.

When calling `sheet.Show()` on a non UI thread, `Show()` will lockup because there is no message loop to handle the UI events.  Use [Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on `ImsMain` to create and show the `ImsSheet` on your UI thread.

Comment: I have to try this but it seems that this could be the problem.